# Android Keystore with large data giving issue,we are using AES/GCM/NoPadding.After a particular range its throwing exception

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, aes, android-keystore

I am facing issues when using AES/GCM/NoPadding, after a particular range its throwing exception and its not encrypting after a range of 65536.I have text length of 131072 , but the encryption is only happeing till 65536.

```
even tried the following as well,
AES/GCM/NoPadding
AES/CBC/pkcs7padding.but after a particular range it is throwing invalidexception.
  
**Note:** 
If I use BouncyCastle provider it is working fine(encryption is happening). But when I use Android keystore with keyspec is not working.
```

even tried the following as well,
AES/GCM/NoPadding
AES/CBC/pkcs7padding.but after a particular range it is throwing invalidexception.

code:

public static EncryptCallBack encryptText(final byte[] textToEncrypt)

```
        throws UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,

        NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,

        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, SignatureException, BadPaddingException,

        IllegalBlockSizeException {
    EncryptCallBack encryptCallBack = new EncryptCallBack();

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey());

    /*Cipher update for Large data and Incremental Encryption */
    byte[] encryptedValue = null;

    byte[] input = textToEncrypt;
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];

    int ctLength = 0;
    try {
        ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
        Log.d("Update ciper","Update"+ ctLength);

    } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
    } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    encryptedValue = cipherText;

    Log.d("Encrypted data Length","Encyrptedlength :"+ encryptedValue.length);

    /*Cipher update for Large data and Incremental Encryption */

    encryptCallBack.setSpecIV(cipher.getIV());
    encryptCallBack.setData(encryptedValue);

    return  encryptCallBack;
}

/*SecertKey*/
 public static SecretKey getSecretKey()  {
        SecretKey key = null;
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = null;
            try {
                keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
                keyStore.load(null);
            } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException |
                    NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
            }
           
            if (!keyStore.containsAlias("alias")) {
                KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
                KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("alias", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                        .build();
                keygen.init(spec);
                key = keygen.generateKey();
            } else {
                KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry("alias", null);
                key = keyEntry.getSecretKey();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return key;
    }

 public static String decryptText(final byte[] encryptedData, byte[] specIV)

            throws UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,

            NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,

            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

        final GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, specIV);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(),spec);

        return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedData), "UTF-8");

    }
```

if anyone come across this kind of situation. please assist.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to encrypt the whole cyphertext in one go, since you only have a `doFinal()` in your code.  That means you are probable hitting a limit on array size or similar.  Decrypt chunk by chunk with `update()` and only use `doFinal()` for the last chunk.  Keep the chunks smaller than 65K obviously.

Comment: after @rossum comment. I tried encrypting chuck by chunk the encryption is working but ,when I tried decrypt ,its giving javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException. I have updated the encryption code as well.Please assist.